# Scrollview in storyboard does not scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I created a scrollview in storyboard with multiple views but the scrollview does not scroll. See the screenshot. I have a scrollview with images and another view embedded that spans outside the view area. I would like the scroll view to scroll down but it does not when I see the code in the simulator.

[image: ft]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a UIView with 1000(or whatever you want) height constant to scrollView and make the UIView equal width to view[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView needs to know its scrollable area, so you need to provide information about width and height for ScrollView's content:

1. width - you can create empty view (with height constraint equal to 1), place it inside scrollView, set its leading and trailing constraints to scrollView and set width constraint equal to main view. Then, scrollView will know that its scrollable area has the same width as screen.
2. height - you need to provide top and bottom constraints for first and last components inside scrollView (and all components should have specified height). I guess you forgot about setting bottom constraint for the last item.